# Get data from json array PHP

Tags: php, json

i decoded the json data using php json_decode
here is my output with print_r

```
stdClass Object ( 
[uv] => stdClass Object ( 
[current] => stdClass Object ( 
[class_name] => delta-positive 
[display] => 668 [value] => 668 ) 
[yoy_perc] => stdClass Object ( 
         [class_name] => delta-negative 
         [display] => -21.23% 
         [value] => -21.23 ) 
[mom_perc] => stdClass Object ( 
         [class_name] => delta-negative 
         [display] => -8.87% [value] => -8.87 ) 
[yoy] => stdClass Object ( 
         [class_name] => delta-negative 
         [display] => -180 [value] => -180 ) 
[mom] => stdClass Object ( 
         [class_name] => delta-negative 
         [display] => -65 
         [value] => -65 ) ) 
[page_title] => example.com 668 UVs for December 2012 | Compete 
[rank] => stdClass Object ( 
        [current] => stdClass Object ( 
           [class_name] => delta-positive 
             [display] => 1,398,481 
            [value] => 1398481 ) [yoy] => stdClass Object ( [class_name] => delta-negative [display] => -187,667 [value] => -187667 ) [last_month] => stdClass Object ( [class_name] => delta-positive [display] => 1,246,200 [value] => 1246200 ) [mom] => stdClass Object ( [class_name] => delta-negative [display] => -152,281 [value] => -152281 ) [last_year] => stdClass Object ( [class_name] => delta-positive [display] => 1,210,814 [value] => 1210814 ) ) )
```

i need to get

```
[display] => 668 [value] => 668 )
```

**668**

of this i tried using foreach but no luck. anyone know how to do that using php an efficient way i mean without a loop
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$obj->uv->current->value
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
object->uv->current->display;
object->uv->current->value;
```

or use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `json_decode()` with the second parameter set to get it to output an array rather than an object structure.

```
`$outputArray = json_decode($inputString, true);
```

That will allow you to loop through it using `foreach()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't feel comfortable with objects you can simply put a "true" to the second parameter of json_decode().

```
json_decode($jsondata, true);
```

So you can access them as an array.

Answer (score 0):

use json_decode($json, true) to get an associative arrays.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php